# Multiple static libraries, swizzling and dispatch_once

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have a main application, let's call it **App**.
It links two *static libraries*, **StatLib1** and **StatLib2**.
**StatLib1** links the **StatLib2** library.

As you see, the **StatLib2** library is linked twice.

---

In a category of the **StatLib2** library, I'm doing some swizzling:

```
+ (void)load {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSLog(@"test");

        [self itk_swizzleInstanceMethodWithSelector:@selector(someMethod:)
                                    withNewSelector:@selector(itk_someMethod:)];
    });
}
```

`test` is logged twice, meaning the methods will be swizzled back to original.
I'm sure that this is the issue, since when I remove the link of **StatLib2** on the **App** target, this does not happen.

---

1. First of all, why does this happen?
2. How can I fix this, without actually removing the link to **StatLib2** on the **App** target?

Comment: Why do you link StatLib1 against StatLib2? It should be sufficient to link the final executable against all static libraries (in the correct order).

Comment: @MartinR StatLib1 is in a different repo, and should be used in different projects as well. For example the unit tests, this means I have to link the unit test target against the StatLib1. Sure that's how it's done?

Comment: I do not have much experience with unit tests, but generally, all static libraries are specified when linking the executable. - Actually, you cannot link one static library agains another one. Perhaps StatLib1 contains a *copy* of StatLib2. You should `NSLog(@"test: %p", self)` in the load method to see if you have two different instances of the class loaded into the application.

Comment: @MartinR `+load` is called when loading a class. It's not an instance, it's a class method. I link **StatLib1** against **Statlib2** the same way I link **App** against **Statlib2**.

Comment: Yes, but what I am currently guessing (and I might be completely wrong) that you are loading two independent copies of the class. Please try to log the class pointer as suggested above. - Or better: `NSLog(@"test: class=%p, token=%p", self, &onceToken)`

Comment: @MartinR I confirm that both point to the same class object.

Comment: @MartinR This makes it hard to understand why the `dispatch_once` isn't working.

Comment: Is `&onceToken` also the same value for both calls?

Comment: Here's the log: 
`test: class=0x7fff7c76cdc8, token=0x100021f60 ---
test: class=0x7fff7c76cdc8, token=0x100021f98`

Comment: @MartinR No, strangely the dispatch tokens aren't the same, while the class is.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44739/discussion-between-martin-r-and-nsaddict)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, a static library is just an archive of object files, so
 you cannot really *link* one static library against another static library.
What probably happens is that all objects of **StatLib2** are *copied* into
**StatLib1**. Later, when the application  is linked, another copy of **StatLib2**
is added to the executable.

So you end with two "instances" of the `load` method, each with its own 
`static dispatch_once_t onceToken`. Both methods are called when the class
is loaded, and each one executes its own `dispatch_once()` block.
This is also shown by the output of

```
NSLog(@"test: class=%p, token=%p", self, &onceToken)

test: class=0x7fff7c76cdc8, token=0x100021f60
test: class=0x7fff7c76cdc8, token=0x100021f98
```

The class is the same (because it is a category for the same class), but the
`onceToken` is different.

As a solution, you should only link the final executable against both 
static libraries.

Comment: Nice analysis! Am a bit late here; and hope this is not out of scope: could you share a link where I can learn more about linking the final .exe to multiple static libraries just to avoid having multiple singletons? Thanks.